# TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len() in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to run this block of codes in terminal with Python:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet
>>> syn = wordnet.synsets('cookbook')[0]
>>> lemmas = syn.lemmas
>>> len(lemmas)
```

And there turned out an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()
```

What's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234498/typeerror-instancemethod-object-has-no-attribute-getitem-with-nltk ;P The printed NLTK  book is rather outdated, follow the electronic version: http://www.nltk.org/book/. I find the howtos page useful for references: http://www.nltk.org/howto/

Comment: @alvas Wow this is awesome, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To call the method `lemmas`, append `()`

```
>>> lemmas = syn.lemmas()
                       ↑↑
```

Comment: This works! Thank you a lot!