# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I'm trying to run these codes with NLTK:

```
>>> gn2 = wordnet.synset('good.n.02')
>>> gn2.definition
'moral excellence or admirableness'
>>> evil = gn2.lemmas[0].antonyms()[0]
```

And there turned out error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What's wrong and how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, `gn2.lemmas` is a method.  To fix it, use `gn2.lemmas()[0].antonyms()[0]`

Comment: Thank you, @zondo. This works. It's so strange on the book there're no "()"s. Is this cause by Python version update?

Comment: There was an API change for NLTK wordnet, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27518899/610569